# How to create custom map with customized markers in android studio XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, user-interface

I have an app that has two activities, main_activity and second_activity. This app allow the user to book the entire house from a map.
From the first activity the user press the button and the second activity open.

Now I would like to implement on the second activity a customized map with customized markers. That looks like this, but I have no idea how to realize it, I have found a pic on google of what similar of what I would like to implement.

[image: map custom]

Could someone help me and explain me how I could reach this result?

Comment: This is possible but first you have to create a map view then see how to add the custom marker icons fro images :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-custom-marker-to-google-maps-in-android/

Comment: Yes, but I would like to obtain that exact kind. not using google maps